# Grails Spring Security UI 403 After overriding auth

Tags: jquery-ui, grails, spring-security

I get a 403 error accessing

```
 http://localhost:8080/tests2ui/plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.4/jquery-ui/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css
```

during login, after overriding spring security auth.gsp using

```
 s2ui-override auth
```

From previous tests, I can determine that the login is successful.

The steps I performed are:

1. Added plugins to BuildConfig.groovy plugins closure:

   `compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"

   compile ":mail:1.0.7"
   compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.4"
   compile ":famfamfam:1.0.1"
   compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"`
2. Create user and role domains

   `s2-quickstart tests2ui User Role`
3. Added Users and Roles to BootStrap.goovy
4. Compile and run app. I am able to log in without errors.
5. Override the auth.gsp using

   `s2ui-override auth`
6. Compile and run app. I get the access denied on the URL

   `http://localhost:8080/tests2ui/plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.4/jquery-ui/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css`

I am using GGTS v3.6.1 and Grails 2.4.3 on a Windows 7 machine.

Any suggestions of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

as noted here:
  [grails spring security ui login weird redirect sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394443/grails-spring-security-ui-login-weird-redirect-sometimes)

The answer is to include a '/plugins/**'  :  ['permitAll'] in grails.plugins.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules.