# grails spring security ui login weird redirect sometimes

Tags: grails, authentication, spring-security

Good day all,

I am working on an application in Grails where I am attempting to use spring security core and ui.  Specifically I have used s2ui-override to override user, role, auth and layout.

Generally it seems to be working.  I have encountered a very odd problem now though and I can't seem to fix it.

When I click on the login link on my home page, I am sent to the s2ui login page as expected.  Once I fill in known credentials and click the login button, I receive a "Sorry you're not authorized to view this page" message; meanwhile the url displayed in the Firefox address panel is

```
http://localhost:8080/galaxy/plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-ui/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css
```

I had this behaviour earlier but (I thought I had) corrected it by adding the following two lines to grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules in my Config.groovy

```
'/login/**':                      ['permitAll'],
'/logout/**':                     ['permitAll']
```

The weird part of this is that if I click back in the browser, I return to the s2ui login panel (fields empty); if I fill them in again (same user) and click the login button, this time I am redirected to my home page as expected.

This behaviour is consistent as far as I can see, that is, it works the second time every time.

Comment: Can you create a unit test that recreates the problem?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion.  I thought that I might first follow the suggestion below, which seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is because the asset being redirected to is being blocked by the Spring Security plugin prompting the login & returning to the requesting asset.

Double check that, grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules, contains a proper entry to match the asset being delivered/requested.

`Config.groovy:`
`grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules =[
'/plugins/**':['permitAll']`

The root cause of this is probably due to the Spring Security UI plugin not (yet?) utilizing the Asset Pipeline which is now default.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!  I will need to read up on the Asset Pipeline a bit, I guess.  Your assistance is greatly appreciated; sorry for the delay in responding, but other work got in the way of this project.

Comment: @MonetsChemist if the problem was a lack of feature or a bug, I would ask you to file it ... burt-beckwith and his team are AWESOME

Comment: @chrislovcnm you are preaching to the choir, as they say hereabouts!  What is missing is a little bit of documentation that says something like "in order to get the things s2ui-override generates to be useful for you, you must edit Config.groovy and at the minimum add..." and those things would be for instance the edit mentioned above.  So I wouldn't call this a bug, except insofar as the documentation is a bit lacking.

Comment: I also had this problem and TheHairyGun's answer did the trick.  I am concerned about security, though.  Is opening up the entire plugin directory safe for All Users?